# UIWebView zoom with iPad Mini

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, ipad-mini

My application developed for iPad contains two UiWebView's, and executes this code to make sure the content fits nicely on the screen:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
   [ipadWebMonth1 stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.style.zoom = 1.7;"];
   [ipadWebMonth2 stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.style.zoom = 1.7;"];
}
```

Theres no way of me testing as I don't own one but as the screen size of the iPad mini is smaller, (I understand the amount of pixels are the same).

But surely this code would zoom the content in too much making some of in unable to be seen as I have user interaction disabled.

What options do I have here? Is there some sort of simulator I can download? Or is there a way of detecting the iPad mini and making a new function with different code?

Thanks,

Jack.

Comment: did you found solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling this in your `viewDidLoad` method (also make sure to remove your JavaScript code):

```
[_webView setScalesPageToFit:YES]
```

It makes the webpage scaled to fit exactly the webview's bounds.

Comment: This doesn't work for some reason, always had problems using this option which is why I resulted to javascript.

Comment: I don't own an iPad mini, but am trying on my normal iPad 2 and it is not working.

Comment: Well, this might be the problem. This method would solve your problem. It's hard to tell why doesn't it work if you don't provide more context/source code.

Comment: What more source code do you want me to provide? I have set the web browsers to scale to fit content in the view did load, and have also tried it in the webviewdidfinishload but none of the content change scale.

Comment: Are you using a XIB file to cosntruct your interface? If so, make sure to check the "Scales Page To Fit" checkbox in the Attribute inspector!

Comment: I'm using a storyboard, the checkbox for the scale to fit is checked for the web browser. :/

Comment: Have you tried loading pages like http://www.apple.com? Maybe it's a problem of the css/javascript that your site uses. Otherwise, it seems something is going wrong in your code.